# Batch file, several lines into single variable

Tags: batch-file

Im trying to make a batch-file Encoder, my current problem is that i dont know how to take a text file, and put all the lines into 1 variable

so if my text file is

```
Hello,

my name is

Benjamin
```

The variable will be either "Hello,my name isBenjamin" (without Spaces between the lines)

or "Hello, my name is Benjamin" (With Spaces between the lines)

The code is

```
@echo off
:a
Cls
echo please input a letter
Set /p input=
if %input%==iamdone goto done
Echo>>temp.txt %input%
type>>temp2.txt %input%.txt
Goto a
:done

This is where i would put the commands im asking 
help for, then i would output the two variables 
(1 from temp.txt and 1 from temp2.txt) into textfiles.
```

Also im using textfiles to do the encryption, because im not advanced enough yet, so the text file a.txt would contain the encrypted letter a

Comment: Batch files are awkward with new lines inside variables, usually `for /f` loops are used to process the files. What exactly are you going to do with that variable? Can you post the complete/relevant code?

Comment: Have you tried "Hello,\nmy name is\nBenjamin" ?

Comment: @kayosoufiane, why do you think this will work in a batch file which is a very primitive Windows scripting language that doesn't understand `\n`?

Comment: @wOxxOm i tried this (echo $'Hello,\nmy name is\nBenjamin') and assumed it will work

Comment: @kayosoufiane, it doesn't work, see the description of the `batch-file` tag.

Answer (score 3):

```
@echo off
setlocal enabledelayedexpansion
set "line="
for /f "delims=" %%i in (bb.txt) do set line=!line!%%i
echo %line%
```

see `for /`, `setlocal /?`, `set /?` and [delayed Expansion](https://stackoverflow.com/a/30284028/2152082)

Answer (score 2):

Next script covers next to any file content - even cmd- and batch-*poisonous* characters `%`, `!`, `<`, `>`, `|`, `^`, ...

Important: note advanced `set` syntax with double quotes `set "varname=varvalue"`.

```
@ECHO OFF
SETLOCAL EnableExtensions DisableDelayedExpansion
rem clear the `_myVar` variable
set "_myVar="
rem  put all the lines from file into `_myVar` variable 
for /F "usebackq tokens=*" %%G in ("D:\bat\SO\files\33824203.txt") do (
  rem put nonempty line into auxiliary variable `_auxVar`
  set "_auxVar=%%G"
  call :addLine 
)
rem remove leading space if any
set "_auxVar="
if defined _myVar set "_auxVar=%_myVar:~0,1%"
if "%_auxVar%"==" " set "_myVar=%_myVar:~1%"

rem unlike `echo(%_myVar%`, next construct would work 
rem even though file contains cmd-poisonous characters %, !, <, >, | etc. 
SETLOCAL EnableDelayedExpansion
  echo(!_myVar!
ENDLOCAL

ENDLOCAL
goto :eof

:addLine
  set "_myVar=%_myVar% %_auxVar%"
  rem                 ^ optional space by design
goto :eof
```

**Resources** (required reading, incomplete):

- (command reference) [An A-Z Index of the Windows CMD command line](http://ss64.com/nt/)
- (additional particularities) [Windows CMD Shell Command Line Syntax](http://ss64.com/nt/syntax.html)
- (`%G`, `%%G` etc. special page) [Command Line arguments (Parameters)](http://ss64.com/nt/syntax-args.html)
- (`set "_auxVar=%_myVar:~0,1%"` etc.) [Extract part of a variable (substring)](http://ss64.com/nt/syntax-substring.html)

Comment: Will fail with many different contents. First challenge `;hello`

Comment: `for /F usebackq^ tokens^=*^ eol^= %%G in ("D:\bat\SO\files\33824203.txt") do (` to treat `;hello` (@jeb's pristine comment). That's why I wrote _next to any_ in sense [**next to** = almost; nearly](http://dictionary.reference.com/browse/next--to?s=t); neither _any_, neither _all_. I suppose sentences under some simple grammar rules, e.g. `Hello, Benjamin!` or `I hate 21 % VAT!` or `Buy it at Jeb&Co!` etc. :)

Comment: And I thought about simple sentences like `Jeb&Co said: "Hello Cat&Dog"` :-) But at all, your solution is nice and should work in the most cases